# Snowflake - Setting Date Time format in result of Query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running a query in snowflake to then export. I need to set/convert a date value to the following format 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss' from 2022-02-23 16:23:58.805

I'm not sure what is the best way to convert the date format. I've tried using TO_TIMESTAMP, but keep getting the following error *'1 too many arguments for function [TO_TIMESTAMP(FSA.LAST_UPDATED, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')] expected 1, got 2'*

Comment: `to_timestamp` is convert text to a timestamp. If you want to present it as text you want `to_char` which does allow formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html) is for string -> timestamp, [TO_CHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html) is for timestamp -> string of which the `TO_CHAR( <date_or_time_expr> [, '<format>' ] )` form is the one you seem to be wanting.

this SQL show string -> timestamp -> formatted string

```
SELECT
    '2022-02-23 16:23:58.805' as time_string,
    to_timestamp(time_string) as a_timestamp,
    to_char(a_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss') as formating_string;
```

| TIME_STRING | A_TIMESTAMP | FORMATING_STRING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-23 16:23:58.805 | 2022-02-23 16:23:58.805 | 2022-02-23T16:02:58 |

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a conversion issue. Please check datatype for your column last_updated. Also seems there is some typo in your question - for the time portion in format, use mi (hh:mi:ss).
Refer below -

```
select to_timestamp('2022-02-23 16:23:58.805'::TIMESTAMP,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.ff')
                                         ;
000939 (22023): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7
**too many arguments for function 
[TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2022-02-23 16:23:58.805'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.ff')] expected 1, got 2**
```

```
select to_timestamp('2022-02-23 16:23:58.805'::string,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.ff');
```

| TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-02-23 16:23:58.805'::STRING,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF') |
| --- |
| 2022-02-23 16:23:58.805 |